# How do I create a custom Rails form component

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I'm trying to refactor some code and I'd like to have my own version of `form.my_component`.

I have something like:

**views/partials/_my_component.html.erb:**

```html
<% helper_text = nil unless defined?(helper_text) %>
<div class="my_component">
  <div><%= label %></div>
  <div><%= form.text_field name %></div>
  <% if helper_text %><div><%= helper_text %></div><% end %>
</div>
```

And I can use it like so:

**some_view.html.erb:**

```rb
<%= form_for @some_obj do |form| %>
  <%= render "my_component",
             name: :some_attribute,
             label: "Some Attr:",
             helper_text: "Enter something valid here."
  %>
<% end %>
```

but I'd like to do something like this instead:

```rb
<%= form_for @some_obj do |form| %>
  <%= form.my_component, :some_attribute, label: "Some Attr:", helper_text: "Enter something valid here." %>
  <%= my_component_tag, :some_attribute, label: "Some Attr:", helper_text: "Enter something valid here." %>
<% end %>
```

How can I add a custom component to the `form` object?

Comment: Never tried it, but looks like you can create custom components like this: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#customizing-form-builders